# Radioactivity of a Fallen Satellite

Tags: physics, terraforming

I'm writing a story where a futuristic world is in ruins, and civilization is replaced with a more primitive population. One of the concepts I'm working on is the idea of ancient megastructures that used to orbit this planet are now crashing on to the earth. What I'm wondering is would these remnants be radioactive, and if so, would they be radioactive enough to harm the individuals who come in contact with the fallen pieces?

Comment: How big are these "megastructures"?  If a city-sized satellite crashes to earth, radioactivity is not the biggest concern.

Comment: That's part of the plot of a Star Wars novel by Timothy Zahnn (crashed Star Destroyer ruins an entire planet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Everything* is radioactive.  Air is radioactive.  Soil and rock are radioactive.  *I'm* radioactive -- and so are you.  The only question is *how* radioactive.

There is a "background radiation" that is normal for our world -- before 1945, it had a certain, low value.  Since the nuclear tests and wartime bombings of 1945 and into the 1980s, and the nuclear accidents of the latter half of the 20th century, it's much higher than it was -- several times the level of 1940, enough so that steel from scrapped warships and building frames made before 1945 is a precious resource where minimal self-radiation is an important factor in sensitive detectors.

Anything that orbits in space will receive more radiation than anything on the ground, even with today's increased background radiation -- but the van Allen Belts protect low orbit from the worst of the radiation environment of space.  Even beyond the Belts, however, the radiation of space doesn't increase the radioactivity of objects, because the only practical ways to do that are to either introduce radioactive material to the object, or to irradiate it with neutrons that can be captured by the nuclei in the material, transforming them from stable or long half life species to those that decay more rapidly (this process is called "neutron activation").  Radiation in space has a very low neutron count, and virtually never a heavy, unstable nucleus, so doesn't tend to make objects more radioactive than they were before they were launched.

An "out" for this, if you have reason to *want* a fallen object to be radioactive, is that one of the more reliable long-term power sources for space machinery is an RTG -- RadioThermal Generator (also known as IGT, Isotope Thermal Generator).  This is a very simple machine consisting of a lump of radioactive material, large enough and active enough to be physically warm or hot -- hot enough to boil water, for instance, or a little hotter -- and a thermocouple system to convert the temperature difference between the hot material and the cold radiating surfaces on the outside directly into electricity.  No moving parts and a decades-long service life.  And residual radioactivity that will persist for millennia, because the decay products of the original isotope are themselves radioactive, as are their decay products, and *theirs*, and so on until after millions or billions of years, it's all turned into lead.

Comment: Wouldn't a nearby star also make these orbiting objects more radioactive though?

Comment: Only if it's emitting low-energy neutrons.  Neutrons aren't a major component of stellar wind or stellar radiation -- the former is mainly hydrogen nuclei and electrons, the former almost entirely EM ranging from long wave radio to gamma.  None of those things have a significant effect on the radioactivity of an object exposed to them.

Answer (score 5):

**Power plant is still kicking out power.**

These orbiting platforms need power.  They will have onboard power plants.  @Zeiss Ikon mentions radiothermal reactors and we have been launching those into space for decades.  I think it would probably be bad to sit on one unless you were wearing thick pants but I don't think a fallen Topaz reactor would be super scary.

We have not launched more powerful nuclear reactors into orbit (or at least not admitted to it) because of the danger they would pose on falling back to earth.  In your world you could have  more formidable and dangerous power plants up there.

Currently we have fission power plants.  That is what makes us electricity and powers nuclear submarines.  A fission plant would need nuclear fuel (radioactive uranium or other isotopes) and would make waste (spent fuel).  If that stuff came down it would be dangerous.  If the thing came down still running and the cooling system broke, it would have a melt down like Chernobyl or Fukushima and that would be bad for the locals.

Our tech does not include working fusion power plants but I want them and they would be great.  You could have one of those.  They don't produce nuclear waste the same way but they could be expected to kick out a lot of radiation, and if the shielding failed but the thing kept running that could be even more dangerous than a fallen fission reactor.

---

Best though: you do not need to explain.  Your people are primitives!  They don't know what the heck is going on in the thing that fell from the sky.  You can make your thing do what you want it to do for the story.  You want it radioactive - that works fine.  Maybe it is the reactor, or weapons onboard, or some science experiment looking at black holes; something was in there and now it is making bad juju.   Have there be no live vegetation around the fallen platform.  Have the guy who shows up with salvaged loot from the inside of it get sick with radiation sickness.  Readers will figure it out and it will be more interesting along the way.

Comment: Satellites? Zero, they burn up upon re-entry. Mega-structures? depends on if they burn up upon re-entry and were constructed with radioactive materials... that have half-life's longer than whatever period of time that we're talking about....

Comment: @Mazura -  Some big pieces of Skylab hit the ground.  Something shielded like a reactor might also make it down.

Comment: That was a space station though, not (colloquially) a satellite. I'm just mad the OP is semantically correct (they're all 'satellites'). We put RTGs into space all the time, just they're normally on stuff that either exists the solar system, or *would* burn up. This is already a problem in real life ^^ +1.

Comment: Yeah, I used satellites and megastructures interchangeably because I thought anything that orbits a planet is a satellite... additionally, I wasn't even thinking about the radioactive materials used to operate the megastrctures - I was just wondering if the sun's energy would make satellites radioactive if they've been spinning around the planet for millennia.

Comment: @Mazura, [Kosmos 954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosmos_954) hit the ground in sufficiently large pieces that Canada had to spend several million dollars cleaning up the resulting radioactive contamination.

Comment: RTGs tend to be isolated in durable casks for this very reason. Apollo 13 (which, because of the specifics of its return trajectory, had much more energy on reentry than a satellite) [carried an RTG that reentered intact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator#Accidents), no contamination from which has ever been detected.

Answer (score 4):

**In certain instances yes, but generally space debris are not radioactive**

It's difficult to talk about futuristic satellites, but it appears unlikely that Earth-orbiting satellites present any significant radiation hazard. While deep-space missions are commonly powered by nuclear reactors, **Earth-orbiting satellites almost always depend on solar panels.** They had been better than nuclear 30 years ago, and they are even better now. It would be unlikely (but not totally impossible) that in the foreseeable future nuclear fission power would "leapfrog" solar power, and it would become more practical to use the former rather than latter.

Also, you had mentioned "megastructures". While it still appears to be better to use solar power, there may be some other considerations that would justify the use of nuclear power for such structures.

Another source of radioactive material are **scientific instruments** and setups for some experiments. This is the radioactive material definitely out there, and it would be hazardous, but the amount is rather small - after the crash, people have to come to direct contact with the smashed instruments to get radiation sickness.

Yet another possible source of radioactivity is **nuclear weapons**. There are no such weapons in space now (at least if we are not believing any conspiracy theories), but should they be ever deployed, nuclear warheads would present a clear danger to the world below.

One more possibility is the development of **nuclear propulsion**, like [Project Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Prometheus). Today, chemical propulsion provides much more power than available methods of electric propulsion, but this may change. Electric propulsion may justify the use of nuclear reactors, even in near-Earth missions.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way the ancient structures will be hot enough that the primitives will be aware of it.  Things which are highly radioactive have short half lives--and anything that was hot enough for primitives to notice it will have long since decayed by the time the structures are falling out of orbit.

Answer (score 0):

## Meteorites

Random folks discover meteorites which have been travelling through space for thousands, possibly millions of years.  In no case has it been reported that a significant amount of radiation was detected from such a meteorite.  That by itself is a good indication that space does not typically cause objects to become radioactive.

## Half-Life

Even if radionuclides were formed in space, there is the question of how long they would last.  We can only dig up uranium in rocks because uranium has a very long half-life, along with most of the elements used for radioisotope dating.  If a space rock or spacecraft didn't have any U, Pu, Th, etc. already, it would be statistically impossible for the solar wind to impart those to the object.  Note that many daughter products from nuclear decay have relatively shorter half-lives.  So basically the only way for space junk to land with enough radioactivity for primitives to notice is if it had a nuclear reactor aboard.

Note that both fission and fusion reactors will leave radioactive remnants, despite the claims of fusion being a source of "clean" energy.  Most fusion reactions will produce stray neutrons which bombard and irradiate the fusion chamber/coolant/etc.  It won't necessarily create a glowing amount of radioactive material, but possibly enough to sicken folks with long-term exposure, given a sufficiently powerful reactor.  Of course, nuclear fuel rods for a fission reactor will remain radioactive for quite some time, and could easily survive a deorbit in some form, for a sufficiently large ship/station.

Also, most early fusion reactors will likely be D-T, which means they are powered by tritium, a radioactive isotope of hydrogen (because the D-T cross-section is much more favorable than other fuels...it's one of the easiest fusion reactions to start).  A fusion reactor may well have a reinforced tritium fuel tank that survives reentry.

## Realism

Unless your primitives come into contact with mostly intact fuel rods, they may not even notice or understand the danger of the radioactive bits until years later, when folks who were exposed have greater incidences of cancer/etc.  If you want a realistic level of danger, then I would propose that scavengers who discover but quickly pass by crashed ruins suffer no lasting effects.  But folks who scavenge actual reactor parts, and turn them into jewelry and/or ceremonial weapons/etc. do suffer from cancer/tumors/acute radiation sickness.  They may notice used fuel rods stored in a heavily reinforced water tank with the blue glow of [cherenkov radiation](https://www.thoughtco.com/blue-reactor-water-cherenkov-radiation-4037677).  They might decide that this is a kind of magical force, and turn it into jewelry.  Soon, the most powerful primitives walk around with the blue-glow jewelry, until it eventually makes them sick.  Then others say that the gems are cursed, leading to all kinds of interesting developments.